# Internet not working through Ethernet

Tags: internet, ethernet

Previously it was working fine, But after re-installing ubuntu this problem emerged. I can easily login through my ISP web page, But after that I can not be able to connect to the internet (I tried pinging to google but it didn't worked). In windows I can easily login and surf the net, But in ubuntu it's not working.

Below is the screen shot of ifconfig command in ubuntu

[image]

Comment: Have you tried pinging google dns : `ping -c 1 8.8.8.8`  ?

Comment: check `/etc/resolv.conf` file what does it have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take note that the network is not attached to "eth0" which is where it should normally be attached.

Try running `ifconfig enp2s0 down` then `ifconfig enp2s0 up` then check the status `ifconfig enp2s0` you can verify that is has the right network details

Also, if that didn't work. Try to manually assign ip address to eth0 to  isolate the issue

```
ifconfig eth0 172.29.70.31 netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast 172.29.70.255
ifconfig eth0 up
```

Last thing is to check if it is routing correctly.

```
route -n
```

Answer (score 0):

Dns problem for sure when you can reach your isp's login page.

run these codes if internet works then change the settings accordingly to your network-manager and firewall

```
sudo -i
iptables -I OUTPUT 1 -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I OUTPUT 2 -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT 2 -p udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
echo "nameserver 208.67.222.222" > /etc/resolv.conf
echo "nameserver 208.67.220.220" >> /etc/resolv.conf
```